# location.path does not redirect to new location?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-routing

I am trying to get my head around redirecting from the login page in angular js. I have 2 links a secure one and a public one in my route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/customers', {
            controller: 'CustomersController',
            templateUrl: 'customers.html',
            secure: true
        })
        .when('/login/:redirect*?', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login.html'
        })
        .when('/testing', { templateUrl: 'testing.html' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

}]);
```

When I click on the customers link and login with email 'admin@mail.com' and password does not matter , the location which is the customers.html template is not shown:

```
  if ($scope.email != "admin@mail.com") {
    $scope.errorMessage = 'Unable to login';
    return;
  }

  if ($scope.email == "admin@mail.com" && $routeParams && $routeParams.redirect) {
    path = path + $routeParams.redirect;
  }

  $location.path();
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/nvp3eoDn1bv6XNCqzfQx?p=preview

Comment: Maybe that error is occurring because a digest cycle is already in progress and you're calling `$scope.$apply()` within that digest?

Comment: I removed the $scope.apply no error but still not goin to right page? updated the plunkr too:http://plnkr.co/edit/nvp3eoDn1bv6XNCqzfQx?p=preview